# LTSP client boots on busybox

Tags: boot, server, virtualbox, ltsp, ltsp-client

I've installed an LTSP server on my linux desktop 12.04 (virtual machine), set all the necessary network settings.

Now I created a thin client using virtualbox, booted (after starting up the server obviously), the client connects to the ip address, boots, but all i see is a busybox.

Shoudln't there be a desktop??

I tried installing an LTSP server on a 10.04 desktop, this time the client booted in a busybox with this error:
Error: failed to connect to NBD server.

I followed this guide : http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-create-ubuntu-1104-x64-ltsp-server-32bit-thin-clients

except for the client I created a "host only" NIC instead of a bridged one.

I've really been stuck with this for a long time, could somebody please help?

Comment: Really? :/ No one knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Turns out the nbd-server config had the wrong export path

go to /opt/nbd-server/config

under

```
[export]
    exportname= /opt/ltsp/images/i386.img
    port = 2000
```

restart the nbd-server witht he command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nbd-server restart
```

Also, I'm not sure but I suspect that you have to chose a static IP address different from the gateway address.

and voilà solved.

Comment: This also seems to work in Ubuntu 16.10, although the config file is in /etc/nbd-server and the '[export] section must be added all together.