# Mate 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial) client boot issue, boots on Busy Box

Tags: boot, 16.04, mate, ndb

After installing Mate 16.04 32bit LTS Xenial as server system, fat clients fail to boot. Instead, boot reaches this point

```
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... Begin: Setting up nbd-client registered device at major 43 ... Negotiation: ..Error: Read failed: End of file
Exiting. 
done.
```

Then some more messages follow and then this:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    - Check root= (did the system wait for the right fevice?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/nbd0 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

And then goes to BusyBox.

Looking at solutions here: [LTSP client boots on busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517121/ltsp-client-boots-on-busybox), I have no nbd folders or files in `/dev` or `/opt`.

I was previously using 12.04 LTS with no problem.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works, as well as the fact that the patch has not reached the packages in the repository yet. The bug affects both fat and thin clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the [solution here](http://alkisg.mysch.gr/steki/index.php?topic=7230.0).

For those who do not speak Greek, the solution is actually similar to the one in [the link I mention in the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517121/ltsp-client-boots-on-busybox?noredirect=1&lq=1), but not quite. In my case the file `/etc/nbd-server/conf.d/ltsp_i386.conf`, which is originally not at all created- and that is the bug, has to include the following:

```
[/opt/ltsp/i386]
     exportname = /opt/ltsp/images/i386.img
     readonly = true
     authfile = /etc/ltsp/nbd-server.allow
```

An nbd-server restart is required:

```
sudo service nbd-server restart
```

PS System restart may be required.